# Reordering bag of bag with ng2-dragula

Tags: angular, npm, draggable, drag

I'm using [ng2-dragula](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula) for some rich sorting UI. I got it working to the point where I can reorder any of the `<li>` elements.

```
<div *ngFor="let bag of chest" class='container'>
  <ul [dragula]='"bag-one"' [dragulaModel]='bag'>
    <li *ngFor="let item of bag">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My `chest` variable is an array of array: `[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]`. So I can move any `<li>` freely within and even between the 2 `container` divs. What I want to do is being to reorder the ENTIRE div itself.

I tried the following but no luck:
`<div *ngFor="let bag of chest" class='container2' [dragula]='"bag-one"' [dragulaModel]='chest'>`

Answer (score 0):

You should create dynamic angular bag name for each container.

```
<div *ngFor="let bag of chest; let i of index" class='container'>
  <ul [dragula]='"bag"+i' [dragulaModel]='bag'>
    <li *ngFor="let item of bag">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The code `'"bag"+i'` will generate the new bag for each iteration.